# Is the composition of monotone operators monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, monotone-operator-theory

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle: H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and induced norm $\left\| \cdot \right\|: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Let $A, B : H \rightarrow H$ be [monotone operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_operator), that is (for both $A$ and $B$) 
$$ \langle A x - Ay, x-y\rangle \geq 0 \quad \forall x,y \in H$$

I am wondering if $A \circ B$ is monotone as well, that is, if 
$$ \langle A B x - A B y, x-y\rangle \geq 0 \quad \forall x,y \in H$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the linear operator $A x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$. Observe that it is monotone and consider $B=A$.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you may be interested in [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758938/projection-and-pseudocontraction-on-hilbert-space].

Comment: What if $B$ is increasing and affine [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782681/composition-of-monotone-and-increasing-mappings]?